# No Java Virtual Machine was found while installing eclipse

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, installation

I have downloaded "eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz" from www.eclipse.org for linux-64 bit OS.
When i tried to run the installer, by double clicking on it. It showed the error

"A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java Virtual Machine was found after searching the following locations:
/home/shubham14/Downloads/Softwares/eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-linux-gtk-v86_64/eclipse/jre/bin/java
java in your current path."

I dont understand why this error has occured since i have jdk 14 already installed and its path is also set.

Comment: Why are you trying to install a release which is 8 years and 14 releases old? Most likely you have Java 9 or later installed - Juno won't work with anything after Java 8 (and possibly not even 8)

Comment: Are you sure Java is installed under `/home/shubham14/Downloads/Softwares/eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-linux-gtk-v86_64/eclipse/jre/bin/` ?

Comment: Jenea, I have Java 14 installed at location - "/home/shubham14/Desktop/jdk-14"

Comment: When i added the line -vm /home/shubham14/Desktop/jdk-14/bin/java to the eclipse.ini file. Eclipse started but further an error occured.  I think problem might be what Greg is suggesting.

Comment: I installed eclipse through oomph installer. Successfully installed it.  Thanks